# How to manipulate the order of a plot by arranging the data frame

Tags: r, sorting, plot, ggplot2, tidyverse

Usually when I want to reorder for example a bar chart I use the `reorder()` function on the ggplot axes. Now this is an option but it sometimes confuses me after `coord_flip()` and I don't really like this way of doing things. I rather manipulate the data itself.

My data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

warCasualties <- tibble(Who = c("N. Vietnam + communist allies",
               "South Vietnam",
               "Vietnamese civilians",
               "United States",
               "Allied forces"),
       Type = c("Military",
                "Military",
                "Civilians",
                "Military",
                "Military"),
       Estimated.deaths = c((950765 + 1100000)/2,
                            (110000 + 313000)/2,
                            2000000,
                            58220,
                            5341))
```

I want to do the following but my plot won't order like the data frame does.

```
warCasualties %>%
  arrange(desc(Estimated.deaths)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Estimated.deaths, y = Who)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = Who, xend = Estimated.deaths, yend = Who)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package `forcats` for it's function `fct_inorder()`, which will set the levels of the factor to the order in which they apprear in your arranged tibble. `ggplot()` is looking for a factor variable to determine the axis order and if it's not a factor it will be coherced with `as.factor()` (silently) producing the alphabetical ordering that you are seeing.

```
library(forcats)

warCasualties %>%
    arrange(desc(Estimated.deaths)) %>%
    mutate(Who = forcats::fct_inorder(Who)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Estimated.deaths, y = Who)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = Who, xend = Estimated.deaths, yend = Who)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

I'm not sure why `forcats` doesn't get loaded with `tidyverse`. It would be a nice addition, since it has some nice factor tools and it's built by Hadley and Co.

Comment: I agree with you that this solution should get loaded in the tidyverse grammar. Weird though.

Comment: To keep from loading more dependencies than necessary, there are non-core tidyverse packages (like forcats) that are installed with tidyverse, but need to be explicitly loaded, library(forcats). http://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

Answer (score 0):

What about this basic solution:

```
  ggplot(warCasualties,aes(x = Estimated.deaths, y = reorder(Who, -Estimated.deaths))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = reorder(Who, -Estimated.deaths), xend = Estimated.deaths, yend = Who)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Use `reorder(Who, -Estimated.deaths)` to have Who ordered from high-low.

Comment: Yes I used to solve the problem like this but I wondered if there's another way, from a data point of view.